NullPointerException PaymentsSetupWizardAccountChangeIntentOperation.onHandleIntent
On our play store pre-launch report we got the following error. We are using google gms but not the wallet service and there is no more context from the logs. Did anybody else experience this and is this related to our app or is this service crash unrelated and only showing on our logs
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3189)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:3167)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:3150)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:202)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:154)
  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call (ContentProviderNative.java:764)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.call (ContentResolver.java:2466)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.call (ContentResolver.java:2446)
  at ekfr.a (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):29)
  at com.google.android.gms.wallet.intentoperation.setupwizard.PaymentsSetupWizardAccountChangeIntentOperation.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):252)
  at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):2)
  at ajdw.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):8)
  at pbh.run (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):70)
  at pbg.run (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):152)
  at elbx.run (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):21)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)


Yes, I have the same error log from Play Console pre-launch report. Is there any clue now

Same error over here too, since June 21. Only on Google Pixel 8, Android 14 though.
Which device is causing you issues?

@HNipps Google Pixel 8 for me also

We got the same error - seems like it is somehow related to app review time. Our app is in review for 8 days so far. something we never had before. Any clue on how to fix it?

@dor506 our app took almost 2 weeks to review

Yes, same error log from pre-launch report.

Please download the log file of the Pixel 8. Especially, look if the first "PRE_ON_CREATE" of "LifecycleMonitor" is way after the reported crash. This would be a clear sign that it is not your app that causes the crash

Is your app a payed app?

I have the exact same stack trace as you.
It seems to be an issue with Google Pixel 8 test devices. There are many reports of the same issue and stack trace on this Unity forum post.
From looking at my Pre-launch reports I can see the exception timestamp is a few seconds before the app is launched and the screen recording shows no crashes.
The only resolution is to exclude Google Pixel 8 from Pre-launch testing or appeal to Google (although I have no idea how long the latter will take to reach resolution).

The same error. After the second attempt the app was approved. Despite the error occurred.

Hi, What do you mean second attempt? You just upload the same version (different build number - I guess) sent to review and they approved it? @Medvedev Ivan

@dor506 Yes, just like that

Go in the Play Console to the details of the exception (the window with the video) and download the full logcat file. I have the same exception and I see in the full logcat, what this exception concerns the "backup" module:
07-17 05:50:58.482 20335 24616 W Backup  : [LegacyBackupAccountManager] No google accounts found!

I think it is a problem with
android:allowBackup="true"

in the AndroidManifest.xml file. And this exception happens only on the Google test system without the Google account.

This makes sense a lot!
I'm going to try this now. If this works, I'd be happy that I solved the problem for more than 2 weeks

@CihadTurhan I also got this error message with allowBackup=false, but Google allowed me to publish the app. And when I get "pre-launch" report by email, the email says that no errors were found. I think it's an internal Google problem and is now being ignored.

I found the solution.
Using Google Play Billing Library 7.0.0 caused the error for me. down grade the library to 6.2.1 and the error is gone.
Use
def billing_version = "6.2.1"
implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"

